# Does $DTIME(2^n)$ contain $NSPACE(n)$ ?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

As in title. Does $NSPACE(n) \subseteq DTIME(2^n)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, for functions $f(n) \in \Omega(\log(n))$, we have that
$$
 \mathrm{NSPACE}(f) \subseteq \mathrm{DTIME}(2^{O(f)})
$$
A proof can be found on slide 28 onwards of the slide set from:

```
 http://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/alg/lehre/ws12_13/KOMPL/folien-eng.pdf
```

I don't know if $\mathrm{NSPACE}(n) \subseteq \mathrm{DTIME}(2^{n})$ is true. TSP is in $\mathrm{NSPACE}(n)$, but the best deterministic algorithm known is in $ \mathrm{DTIME}(n^22^{n})$ (as far as I know).

Comment: Can you provide a link to the slides?

Comment: Hm, I guess the link does not work in closed questions? I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: The proof is standard, and can also be found in Kozen's _Theory of Computation_ (Theorem 2.6) and Papadimitriou's _Computational Complexity_ (Theorem 7.4).